# Trouble with rotatable fade transition

Tags: glsl, shader, transition, fragment-shader

I have this code written in glsl(shadertoy):

```c
#define PI 3.14159265359


vec2 rotate_uv(vec2 uv, float rotation) {
    float center = 0.5;

    return vec2(
        cos(rotation) * (uv.x - center) + sin(rotation) * (uv.y - center) + center,
        cos(rotation) * (uv.y - center) - sin(rotation) * (uv.x - center) + center
    );
}


void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;
    vec2 fade_uv = uv;


    float time = abs(sin(iTime)) * 36.00 / 36.00;
    float angle = 111.00 / 180.00 * PI;


    fade_uv = rotate_uv(uv, angle);


    float alpha = smoothstep(
        1.00 - time,
        1.00 - time,
        1.00 - fade_uv.x
    );


    fragColor.xyz = mix(
        texture(iChannel0, uv).xyz,
        vec3(0.00),
        alpha
   );
}
```

At 0 degree it works fine.
[image: 0 degree test]

But when at 111 degrees it doesn't work correctly.
[image: 111 degree test]

How to make it cover the entire area?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3uJqHHBs -- it might be a bit clumsy, only started playing with GLSL again recently, and my math is still oh so crusty :) I'll see if I can put together some explanation, but it will take some time, and I have some real work to do now. Meanwhile... to see the problem, make two identical squares of paper, put them on top of each other, and rotate one around the center. You'll notice that you'd have to scale one of them (top one bigger or bottom one smaller), in order for the bottom to be completely covered by the top. i.e. you want one square to be inscribed in the other..

Comment: For the math, this image is useful: https://cdn.britannica.com/43/70143-004-CCB17706/theorem-demonstration-squares-proof-Pythagorean-b-square.jpg | Make `a+b=1` and angle opposite to `a` be the rotation angle (mod 90 degrees). Calculate length of `a` from the rotation angle using trigonometry, then `c` from `a` using Pythagoras theorem. The `c` is your scaling factor.